# Intervention- usage

Tags: meaning-in-context

I would like to express *disturbing of  behavior of application*, such as showing a message box when an event is occurring in the application.
Does the word **intervention** mean so?

Does the use of *intervention* here sound OK?

> Intervention in application pre and post element creation events

Comment: I honestly don't understand what `Intervention in application pre and post element creation events` means... So no...

Comment: basically **no**, you wouldn't use that word for that situation.  i know what you mean: really you'd just say "the app **brings up a message** pre and post element creation".  you might say a "modal message" if you're 100 years old, that used to be the typical situation

Comment: Does the application have substance abuse issues?

Comment: *Intervention* is exactly what you mean, correct. However, the situation you describe is more complex than mere "intervention." For more appropriate expression/ term, please ask on [programmers.se]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about technical jargon, and should be asked in an IT related group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Intervention has political connotations and would not be used in describing human computer interaction.</s>

**Edit**

Intervention is not the right word to use here but my initial explanation was too simple.

Consider these dictionary usage examples:

- "they are plants that grow naturally without human intervention"
- "the administration was reported to be considering military intervention"
- "two patients were referred for surgical intervention"
- "as her health worsened, her daughters considered staging an intervention"

Each example refers to a party with greater authority, greater expertise, or greater autonomy, interfering in the concerns of another party.

The word intervention has that shade of meaning and should not be used unless that's what is meant.

Comment: What is an example of such usage?

Comment: I have never seen the word intervention used in a human-computer context though - and I am a programmer, gamer, engineer, applications designer, and have 19 years experience using them.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* what you want is this:

> The application has detected errors, and is intervening.

or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds more like you need the word ***interrupt***, as the application is *interrupting* the normal operation or work-flow of the user.

Comment: Yes; however, that word has a different meaning in the given context: that of temporarily pausing the process, which is quite different from what is going on here.

Comment: @Kris from what it sounds like, the OP has some kind of message window that pops up before ("pre") and after ("post") a particular event ("element creation"). If there was an intervention, it would be a permanent change. An interruption especially in computer terms is most certainly a temporary event. An intervention as the meaning of the word is more related to a permanent change of direction or work-flow such as an anti-virus program intervening to prevent these 'elements' from being created, and stopping the installation process for example.